Is there any possibility to integrate NER and Textcat Multilabel Models in the same Pipeline
I am working on extracting information from raw text and have created an NER model with 6 entities. I want to pass the output of the NER model to textcat multilabel models. Specifically, I have created different textcat multilabel models for each entity to improve precision. Now that I have all the models ready, I need guidance on how to add them to the pipeline.
Here are the steps I am trying to implement:
NER Model: Outputs 6 entities in an array.
Textcat Multilabel Models: Use the output from the NER model to get the final output for each entity.
Could anyone provide advice or examples on how to integrate these models into a single pipeline?
Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
